# Deleting QGIS CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I've created a new CRS on QGIS but I assigned a wrong name mistakenly to CRS's name.
Now I have the CRS defined but the name of the CRS is wrong, or not easily identifiable.

I was wondering if there's a way to delete CRS or just customize them?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have set up a `Custom CRS`. You can edit, rename or delete them using `Settings -> Custom CRS`.

Don't forget to click on the diskette symbol to save these changes.

Comment: The answer was right in my face.
I can edit they, by pressing the arrow to right and left.
And then I've clicked on the save (diskette) button to save my edits.
Thanks for the fast reply.